# Algorithm for drawing a straight line with Shift button pressing

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, line

I have line painter widget in my project. So, I have to develope algorithm, which allows to correct line to straight, when user presser Shift key. i have seen similar in Photoshop and Paint.
But my own method doesn't work. I'm working with Qt libs. 
Code here. drawedPoints_ is QList of QPointF

```
void GesturePaintSurface::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)    
{    
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)    
    {    
        isDrawingFinished_ = false;        
        drawedPoints_.clear();    
        firstPoint_ = event->pos();    
        drawedPoints_.append(firstPoint_);    
    }    
    else    
    {    
        event->ignore();    
        isDrawingFinished_ = true;   
    }   
} 

void GesturePaintSurface::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)    
{
    if (!isDrawingFinished_)
    {
        if (isShiftPressed_)
        {
            QPoint newPoint;

            if (abs(drawedPoints_.last().rx() - event->pos().rx()) < 5)
            {
                newPoint.rx() = firstPoint_.x();
                newPoint.ry() = event->pos().y();
            }
            else
            {
                newPoint.rx() = event->pos().x();
                newPoint.ry() = firstPoint_.y();
            }

            drawedPoints_.append(newPoint);
        }
        else
            drawedPoints_.append(event->pos());

        repaint();
    }
}
```

Sorry for my language. thanks in advance!

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: You *really* don't want to maintain a vector of individual points in your line and add one on every mouse move event.
Instead get a QPainter for your widget and redraw a temporary single line on top of the clean widget for every mouse move event with (!isDrawingFinished_). When you're done draw that line for good using whatever method your normally use in your painting application (not a QPainter)

Comment: @Sneftel It is not a streight line! [screenshot] (http://i68.fastpic.ru/big/2015/0109/58/f25cb6ff39598aaf55f49db4f7cb9d58.png)

Comment: @tux3 when I append new point to the list, Qpainter draw line from last point to new

Comment: @DimaGurov that's not the right approach, as you can see it's unmanageable. If you want to draw a line, then just remember where the original point is and draw a clean straight line from that point to the cursor with QPainter. Don't try to build a vector of points, that's way more complicated than necessary.

Comment: For reference, here's some code I wrote that lets you draw a red rectangle over some image in a widget : https://github.com/tux3/Evolve/blob/master/widgetGui.cpp#L323. That rectangle is re-drawn on every mouse event and its coordinate are used to do some computations. You should be able to adapt that code to draw a line instead of a rectangle fairly easily if you want.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you are appending point every time mouse moves! Second problem is that this condition to make vertical or horizontal line is wrong.

It should be like that:

```
void GesturePaintSurface::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)    
{
    if (!isDrawingFinished_)
    {
        QPoint newPoint;
        if (event->modifiers().test(Qt::ShiftModifier)) {
            newPoint = drawedPoints_.last();

            if (qAbs(newPoint.x()-event->x())<qAbs(newPoint.y()-event->y())) {
                newPoint.setY(event->y());
            } else {
                newPoint.setX(event->X());
            }
        } else {
            newPoint = event->pos();
        }
        if (drawedPoints_.count()>1) {
           drawedPoints_.last() = newPoint;
        } else {
           drawedPoints_.append(newPoint);
        }
        update(); // update is better then repaint!
    }
}
```